# boost:python passing an pointer to pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, python, image, pointers, boost

First, i'm not a python programmer, so excuse my silly mistakes.

In C++ I have this public method from MyClass that creates a image dynamically and returns its size.

```
int MyClass::getImg(uchar *uimg[])
{
    int size = variable_size;
    *_uimg = new uchar[size];
    memcpy(*_uimg, imageOrigin->data(), size);
    uimg = _uimg;
    return size;
}
```

And the boost:python:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    class_<MyClass>("MyClass")
        .def("getImg", &MyClass::getImg)
    ;
}
```

and when i try to use it in python:

```
def getImg():
    img = c_char_p()
    size = mymodule.MyClass.getImg(byref(img))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    MyClass.getImg(MyClass, CArgObject, CArgObject)
did not match C++ signature:
    getImg(class MyClass {lvalue}, unsigned char * *)
```

In python I also tried declaring

```
img = POINTER(c_ubyte)()
```

but that did'nt help either.

I googled it around for hours and i didn't came up with any good solution.

I just need access to that image in python, how can i get this done?

Answer (score 0):

Revised and working version, exposing the data as a python list.

I am not sure how to implement this, but there may be a better way of implementing it, if you can choose your python interface freely. I think creating a list may be a better way to expose it. What do you expect from the return value? Maybe you can also wrap it a s a numpy array for better performance (there are also some questions on stackoverflow if you search for boost python and numphy)

```
class TestPtr
{
public:
  int getImg(uchar **uimg)
  {
     int size = 9045;
     uchar *_uimg = new uchar[size];
     for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
       _uimg[i] = i;  

    *uimg = _uimg;
     return size;
 }
};

boost::python::list getImgList( TestPtr &p )
{
  uchar *uimg;
  int rv = p.getImg(&uimg);
  boost::python::list l;
  for ( int i = 0; i < rv; ++i)
    l.append( uimg[i] );
  return l;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
  class_<TestPtr>("TestPtr")
    .def("getImg",&getImgList)
    ;
}
```

Another hint, in your question, you have used the following line to call the method:

```
 mymodule.MyClass.getImg()
```

This will make a class call (more or less equivalent to a static call) to your object. This is a mor ecorrect way to do it:

```
img = mymodule.MyClass()
data = img.getImg()
```